# Self Hosting TinyMCE in ROR with React Project but still getting "domain is not registered"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, tinymce, ruby-on-rails-6

I’m trying to implement. I’ve downloaded the last file from the official website https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/self-hosted and add it under this path “app/javascript/vendor/tinymce.min.js”
But I still receive the apikey error.

[api key error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OqT7.png)
I’m using rails 6 with React on the frontend and I’ve installed the official TinyMCE React component with yarn.

Adding the script to **application.html.erb** file end up with this error
[application.html.erb error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3PHP.png)

here is my  **application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test TinyCME</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <script src="../../javascript/vendor/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is my react component where I'm putting the editor

```
import React from "react";
import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";

const index = () => {
  const handleEditorChange = (content, editor) => {
    console.log("Content was updated:", content);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Editor
        name="content"
        initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
        init={{
          height: 500,
          selector: "textarea",
          branding: false,
          menubar: false,
          plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table paste code",
          ],
          toolbar:
            "undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
             alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
             bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat",
        }}
        onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default index;
```

It seems that it's also possible to self-hosted with web pack but I don't see how I can do that so If someone already did it. He/She could be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an API key error while trying to use TinyMCE self hosted, that means that the Tiny React Wrapper cannot find your self hosted installation of Tiny (or more specifically that it didn't find the `tinymce` variable made available) so, it attempts to load TinyMCE from the Cloud.

Cloud TinyMCE expects an API key, and then checks that API key for registered domains. You are not sending a key, and so TinyMCE cannot confirm the domain it is being loaded from is "allowed" to load it.

Using Self Hosted TinyMCE with React, you have two different deployment options.

1. Deploy TinyMCE independent of the React application: add a script to either the `<head>` or the end of the `<body>` of the HTML file.
2. Bundling TinyMCE with the React application using a module loader such as Webpack and Browserify. [Here's some more information about using TinyMCE with module loaders](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/).

Comment: An easy way to do 1. is to use the [tinymce-rails gem](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails).